# Mongo - sort while loop

Tags: php, sorting, mongodb

Ok i am using mongo db and have a repeating region on my page:

```
try {

    $connection = new Mongo();
    $database   = $connection->selectDB($selectDB);
    $collection = $database->selectCollection($selectCollection);

} catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
    die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}

$cursor = $collection->find();

while ($cursor->hasNext()): $document = $cursor->getNext(); 


                        echo $document['fieldName']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['fieldType']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['fieldLength']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['user_id']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['order']."<br/>";
                        echo "<hr/>";

 endwhile;
```

this works fine but what i am trying to do now is sort by user_id.  I have tried this:

```
 try {

    $connection = new Mongo();
    $database   = $connection->selectDB($selectDB);
    $collection = $database->selectCollection($selectCollection);

} catch(MongoConnectionException $e) {
    die("Failed to connect to database ".$e->getMessage());
}

$cursor = $collection->find().sort({user_id: -1});

while ($cursor->hasNext()): $document = $cursor->getNext(); 


                        echo $document['fieldName']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['fieldType']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['fieldLength']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['user_id']."<br/>";
                        echo $document['order']."<br/>";
                        echo "<hr/>";

 endwhile;
```

The line i altered is the:  $cursor = $collection->find().sort({user_id: -1});

i am getting php error when id o this.  Can someone show me the proper syntex to get this array to sort.

I have also tried:

```
$cursor = $collection->find()->sort({user_id: -1});

and 

 $cursor = $collection->find();
 $cursor = $cursor.sort({user_id: -1});
```

Any help would be appreciated.  thanks.

***answer found****

```
$cursor = $collection->find();
$cursor->sort(array('user_id' => 1));
```

Comment: Sorry i think im starting to rely on SOF a little too much and getting a little post happy.  After about another 2 mins of searching i found the answer.  I posted it in my original post at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a PHP syntax error:

```
$collection->find().sort({user_id: -1})
```

is invalid PHP. In PHP, the dot operator ("`.`") is used to concatenate strings, not to access object members. For that, use the arrow operator ("`->`"). Additionally, "`{user_id: -1}`" is not correct syntax for an associative array in PHP. For that, use "`array("user_id" => -1)`".

This gives us:

```
$collection->find()->sort(array("user_id" => -1))
```

which I believe should work.